# Java Beginner can't figure out how to start programming

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started learning Java and I don't know how to start programming.  I just get an error when i try to create a class file.

package main;

public class Main {

}

This is the only code I have in my program and I haven't started coding yet.  Am i missing a key thing or are the errors normal?

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials, you should get one that fits your needs...

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: This is the jackpot for asking better questions; http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: And tutorials can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. When you've read the relevant ones and still have questions, please come back and ask again.

Comment: At the very least, specify **what errors**. They're there to *tell* you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout this article

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

The example class provided in the article is:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your main inside a Class. Also the main has to be `static`:

```
public class MainClass{

    public static void main (String [ ] args) {

        // Code here

    }
}
```

Anyway, you should start learning from some tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/

Comment: Please don't encourage that awful comment style.  They add no information and just clutter the code base.

Comment: I was trying to help him to understand the code if he is a total beginner.

Comment: Code should be Self explanatory, like reading a book.

Comment: Commendable, but that's not how to do it.